# Group data in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to group the data that I get from mongoDB by repo Id 
my collection structure is:

```
{ 


"id":"8820624457",
   "type":"CreateEvent",
   "actor":{ 
      "id":27394937,
      "login":"Johnson0608",
      "display_login":"Johnson0608",
      "gravatar_id":"",
      "url":"https://api.github.com/users/Johnson0608",
      "avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/27394937?"
   },
   "repo":{ 
      "id":163744671,
      "name":"Johnson0608/test",
      "url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Johnson0608/test"
   },
   "payload":{ 
      "ref":"master",
      "ref_type":"branch",
      "master_branch":"master",
      "description":null,
      "pusher_type":"user"
   },
   "public":true,
   "created_at":"2019-01-01T15:00:00Z"
}
```

my code is :

```
    collection.find({}).project({ 'repo.id': 1, 'actor.login': 1, 'type': 1 }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");    


      res.status(200).json({ docs });
      callback(docs);
});
```

I am trying to group by repo id but i don't know how(I am new to mongoDB)

Comment: In which format do you want data after group by `repo.id`?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda { 
   "repo":{ 
      "id":163744671
   },
   "actors":[ 
      { 
         "login":"Johnson0608"
      }
   ]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this [MongoPlayAround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/93oSQUpK1rm)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
   $group: {
    _id: "$repo.id",
    Actors: {
      $push: {
        "login": "$actor.login"
      }
    }
  }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) function.

> Groups input documents by the specified **_id** expression and for each distinct grouping, outputs a document. The **_id** field of each output document contains the unique group by value.

```js
collection
  .find({})

  .aggregate({
       $group: {
           _id : 'repo.id'  // The thing you want to group by
           // ... Other arguments
       }
   })

  .project({'repo.id': 1, 'actor.login': 1, 'type': 1})
  .toArray(function (err, docs) {

    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");    


    res.status(200).json({ docs });
    callback(docs);
});
```